# Defining functions by input

Tags: function, recursion, wolfram-mathematica

I seem to have a problem in Wolfram Mathematica. My goal is to define the function y[k], which may contain recursion, and some values of an undefined function u[k]. So basically the function should look something like this:
y[k]=a1*y[k-1]+a2y[k-2]+...+b1u[k]+....
I am having some problems with the definition of the function y: I want to have the function by Input[], so my program will be able to solve for any y functions. The problem lies in the recursion part, please note that this indeed WORKS:

```
y[k_] = Input[]
```

until the Input does NOT contain any recursive expressions (for example if I type in u[k]+8u[k-5], it works flawlessly).
However, if I input anything that does contain recursion, for example:

```
1+y[k-1] (even if I define y[0]=0)
```

Then I get a recursion depth exceeded error. If i declare virtually the same function hardcoded into the program like this:

```
y[k_]:=1+y[k-1] y[0]=0
```

The program works flawlessly. Could someone possibly help me out, so I'll be able to input a function that contains recursion? Thank you!

Addition: I even tried it like this, to no avail:

```
c=Interpreter["MathExpression"][Input[]]
y[0]=0
y[k_]:=c
```

Declaring the following way is not desirable as it asks for Input anytime the function y is called:

```
y[k_]:=Input[]
y[0]=0
```

Comment: recommend you ask this on mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I'm always stunned that relatively novice Mathematica users (please forgive me when I'm wrong) come up with approaches that need a deeper understanding of the evaluation of expressions and why they choose so complicated ways.

OK, here is what happens: When you write `y[k_]=Input[]` the right side is instantly evaluated and you want it that way because you want to input your definition. However, the moment you press Enter in your Input, the evaluation does not stop so Mathematica instantly tries to evaluate what you have put there. If you have used `y[k-1]` then Mathematica tries to evaluate this and ends up in an infinite recursion.

If you really want to do what you try to do, then you need to inject the right-hand side expression without evaluating it directly. Please beware that this is fragile and you are on a path with many holes to fall in. What you could do is for instance the following

```
y[1] = 1;
(y[k_] := #) &[Input[]]
```

and in the input, you insert something like `1+y[k-1]`. I am confident that there is a much better way for you underlying problem that you did not describe.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Yes I'm quite new to Mathematica, and I read everything I could find on defining functions(for example what you mentioned), but I couldn't find a solution to the problem. I thought of storing the values in a matrix, but then again I wouldn't be able to enter any expression-only those that do fit in the matrix of a given size. I will try to do this with matrices, thank you for the warning.